# Magento adding form attachments

Tags: magento, attachment

I tried following this:
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/adding-upload-field-in-contact-form-and-send-as-attachment/

But the attachments wont send? I only get a nonname file with no extension and no file size - as mentioned by some of the commenters on that blog.

Step 2 is a bit vague I guess I am missing that bit?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is you form enctype=”multipart/form-data”?

Comment: Yep done that part. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

What file are you trying to upload?  Is it one of the allowed file types - zip/jpg/doc/docx etc.?

If you check your /media directory, has a 'contacts' directory been created in there?  Is the uploaded file in that directory?

Comment: I tried all kinds. Just sends a file called "noname" if you read the comments on that blog a heap of others have the same problem but dont really mention how to fix it.

I also made that directory and chmod it to 77. Still doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

I fixed it somehow.

I re-read the comments on the thread here:
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/adding-upload-field-in-contact-form-and-send-as-attachment/

And put a xml from point 2 in the tut (which was quite vague) into 2 spots that the commentator recommended, not sure which one did it but it now works.

app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml

Or this one:

***"Thnx for you post. It is working perfect.
i thing you miss one thing ."
create xml file MagePsycho_Customcontact.xml in app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Customcontact.xml***

```
<config>
<modules>
<magepsycho_customcontact>
<active>true</active>
<codepool>local</codepool>
</magepsycho_customcontact>
</modules>
</config>
```